# How to reduce noise on android accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, noise

I am developing an application to find the position of an android phone relative to some starting point for a robotics project I am working on. The maximum range that the robot would travel is a 12 ft by 12 ft square. I am open to other ways of doing this as well. Currently, I am using the accelerometer to find the position of the robot on the field, but the noise on the robot is messing with the integration calculations. Here is a copy of my code.

```
   double currentVelocity;
   double currentPosition;
   float noise[] = new float[3];
   float alpha = (float) 0.1;
   private static final double timeInterval = .25;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {
        //X,Y,Z values for the acceleration in meters per second squared
        float xAccelCurrent_RAW = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float yAccelCurrent_RAW = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float zAccelCurrent_RAW = sensorEvent.values[2];

        noise[0] = alpha * noise[0] + (1 - alpha) * sensorEvent.values[0];
        noise[1] = alpha * noise[1] + (1 - alpha) * sensorEvent.values[1];
        noise[2] = alpha * noise[2] + (1 - alpha) * sensorEvent.values[2];

        float xAccelCurrent_filtered = xAccelCurrent_RAW - noise[0];
        float yAccelCurrent_filtered = yAccelCurrent_RAW - noise[1];
        float zAccelCurrent_filtered = zAccelCurrent_RAW - noise[2];

        String xPositionString = Double.toString(findPosition(findVelocity(xAccelCurrent_filtered, timeInterval), timeInterval));
        String yPositionString = Double.toString(findPosition(findVelocity(yAccelCurrent_filtered, timeInterval), timeInterval));
        String zPositionString = Double.toString(findPosition(findVelocity(zAccelCurrent_filtered, timeInterval), timeInterval));

        xAccelTextView.setText(xPositionString);
        yAccelTextView.setText(yPositionString);
        zAccelTextView.setText(zPositionString); }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Low pass filter is your solution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter

```
protected float[] lowPass( float[] input, float[] output ) {
    if ( output == null ) return input;     
    for ( int i=0; i<input.length; i++ ) {
        output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I know that. I tried to implement a low pass filter within my code, but I'm not sure if I did it properly.

Comment: `noise[0] = alpha * noise[0] + (1 - alpha) * sensorEvent.values[0];`
       

        `float xAccelCurrent_filtered = xAccelCurrent_RAW - noise[0];`